# Vectors and Cartesian Equation

Tags: vectors

Consider a plane with the x,y, and z-intercepts equal to a, b, and c respectively. Find the Cartesian equation of the plane.

I know that the Cartesian of a plane is Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this version of the Cartesian equation $A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0) + C(z-z_0)=0$.  You should be able to figure out an $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ pretty quick.  Then to figure out $A$, $B$, and $C$ you need to find an expression for a vector orthogonal to your plane.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Assume that $a, b, c \ne 0$, so you can substitute the points $(a,0,0), (0, b,0), (0, 0, c)$ into the equation

$Ax+By+Cz=-D$ (and take $D=-1$ for convenience) to solve for $A, B, C$.